# Translations of "to try"

Tags: word-requests

Can someone please help me clarifying all the possible ways to say "try" in Chinese. As in "try sth" or "try to do sth". I can come up with many translations but it's very hard for me to use them in context.

Answer (score 3):

A simple form of try is 试一试： ‘试一试某事’ = 'give something a whirl/shot'
I often hear:
我不会！ I can't do it!
试一试！ Try!

You can often replace 试一试 with 尝试。

You can also use 试： 我可以试一下这双鞋吗？

try hard (to do sth.) is 努力： 如果你努力就能够做到。

also 尽力： try your hardest (to do sth.): 我们会尽力完成。

Comment: 试试 or 试一试 is reduplication of the verb  试. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26236/why-are-there-duplicates-in-the-following-words-%e6%b8%b8%e6%b8%b8%e6%b3%b3-%e5%8c%96%e5%8c%96%e5%a6%86-%e6%95%a3%e6%95%a3%e6%ad%a5-etc  试试 means try slightly; 试一试 means try once/ try slightly.

Comment: In ’试一试 ‘ ’一试‘ cannot be a verb. How could you count a verb? What would that mean?

Comment: In 试一试, the first 试 is a verb. 一 is the counting word and the second 试 is a 'verb classifier'  - for counting how many 'try' you have tried. Let me give you another example., 看一看= look one look. (take one look/ look briefly)

Answer (score 2):

> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/try
>
> try:
>
> 1.to make an attempt at —often used with an infinitive-  *try to fix the car*

~

> https://translate.google.ca/#en/zh-TW/try
>
> 嘗試 - try, attempt
>
> 企圖 - try, attempt
>
> 試圖 - try, attempt

- 嘗試 emphasizes on "the action of trying"
- 企圖 emphasizes on "intention of trying"
- 試圖 emphasizes on "the uncertain nature of trying"

> "他嘗試修理這輛汽車" (he try to repair this car) emphasizes on his action of trying to fix it.

~

> "他企圖修理這輛汽車" (he try to repair this car) emphasizes on his intention of trying to fix it.

~

> "他試圖修理這輛汽車" (he try to repair this car) emphasizes on his uncertain attempt to fix it.

~

> 試著 is the colloquial counterpart of 嘗試
>
> "他試著修理這輛汽車"

More examples:

嘗試種花 (try to grow flower) - *let me see how you do it.*

企圖謀殺 (try to murder)- *it is your intention, isn't it?*

試圖打敗職業拳擊手 (try to defeat a pro boxer)- *are you sure?*