# What's the difference between 听 and 听听?

Tags: difference

> 你们在聊什么？我想听。
>
> 你们在聊什么？我想听听。

I think 听 is stiff, and 听听 is more casual.
How do I express that diffeneces in English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there duplicates in the following words 游游泳, 化化妆, 散散步, ..., etc?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26236/why-are-there-duplicates-in-the-following-words-%e6%b8%b8%e6%b8%b8%e6%b3%b3-%e5%8c%96%e5%8c%96%e5%a6%86-%e6%95%a3%e6%95%a3%e6%ad%a5-etc)

Comment: Where did you get this? I think it might be better to say '让我听一下‘ than 我想听

Comment: grammar topic: verb reduplication/动词的重叠, search site: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=verb+reduplication,

Comment: 请看我: please look at me, 请看看我/请看一下我: please take a look at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double verb will make your speaking sounds more casual, natural, cute, free,

Your username reminds me the meme

[image]